# Save image as RGBA8 in PNG

Tags: python, png, python-imaging-library

I am trying to save an image in PNG and would like to preserve transparency and optimize for size. 64 colors are enough.

I think I already had the solution with Python's Pillow, but have lost it. Here is the result I'm looking for (RGBA PNG with 64 colors):

[image]

I'm trying with this:

```
tile_opt = tile.convert("RGB").convert("P", palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=64)
tile_opt.save(currenttiles_path + "/" + fname, "PNG", optimize=True)
```

But I am loosing alpha with `convert("RGB")`. If I try `convert("RGBA")` then Python says image is not in right format.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you trying to save full transparency for each pixel, or is bilevel transparency (on/off) enough?

Comment: I need full transparency for each pixel. The reason I need it is because of the borders which get gradually more transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using [pngquant](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pngquant/) ([website](https://pngquant.org/)).

I still have to figure out how to use the module within Python but was able to get proper result by invoking the following command from Python with `os.system()`:

`pngquant ---output final.png 64 original.png`